# Once you use the exits, you're finally inside me

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I think this riddle is not already on this site (I couldn't find it, but I think it is well known and it should be).

> I have one entrance and two exits.
>   Once you use the exits, you're finally inside me.

What am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it is

> pants

And it is self-explanatory

Comment: Well, that was quick :)

Comment: @oleslaw first thing came to mind was shirt though :)

Comment: Actually, there are 3 exits with the zipper.

Comment: @Marc well zipper is the part of entrance right?

Comment: @smriti Also an exit for men XD

Answer (score 3):

I think

> [Andy Dufresne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Robbins)'s cell in [*The Shawshank Redemption*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shawshank_Redemption).
>  
>   [image]

Comment: SPOILER ALERT!!